# Asking for user input without pausing code / connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, frontend

So I'm working on a simple chat app so I can work with servers and clients, but I'm running into this issue on the client with messages not showing up, and I figured out this is because of the way I ask the user to type / send messages.

Every time that you send a message on one client, it will not show up on the other until you send another message, so I was wondering if there was another way to ask for input without disrupting the flow of receiving messages. [Image of what's going on (Timestamps added for clarity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtBRg.png)

I'm using the Prompt-Sync module.

This is the code for receiving messages, slightly slimmed down for extra readability:

```js
const msg = prompt("> ")
if (msg.toLowerCase().split(" ")[0] == "~switch") {
   const tosw = msg.split(" ")[1]
   const valid = await axios.get("http://"+server+":7072/user/"+tosw)
   if (valid.data['exists']){
        ChattingWith = tosw
        console.log("you are now chatting with ??")
        prm()
        return
    } else {
        console.log("invalid username")
        prm()
        return
    }
}

socket.emit('sendmsg', msg, ChattingWith)
```

I tried to use multi-threading but couldn't figure out a way to integrate that with the way I was receiving messages.

I just couldn't find any modules or things on this, I know that there is probably a VERY easy fix or change I can do to achieve this but I'm slightly new with this kinda stuff so I just thought I could get some help from this community, so do you guys have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the native `readline` API.

Be warned it's not intuitive at all, and the docs aren't great.

Readline docs: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Here's an example that will write a received message and move the user's input down one line: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-8eprb8?file=index.js

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

rl.setPrompt('> ');
rl.on('line', sendMsg);
rl.prompt();

function sendMsg(msg) {
  console.log('* Sending ' + msg + '...');
  socket.emit('sendmsg', msg)
  rl.prompt();
}

function receiveMessage(msg) {
  const line = rl.line;
  readline.clearLine(rl, 0);
  readline.cursorTo(rl, 0);
  rl.write('# ' + msg);
  rl.clearLine(1);
  rl.prompt();
  rl.write(line);
}
```